# ImageView without scaling

Tags: android, imageview, scaling

I have a ListView that shows rows

This is the xml:

```
 ...
  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".30">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/face"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".70"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:padding="4dp" >

            // Other views...

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    …
```

and get this result:

[image]

this is the original image

[image]

need is the image without scaling, just like this:

[image]

I am using android: ScaleType = "centerCrop" I tested with android: adjustViewBounds = "true" and many other parameters, but never successfully

Ideas?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set your image to `android:src` instead of `android:background`.

```
<ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/face"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

All views can take a background image

The `src` to an `ImageView` has additional features:

- different [scaling types](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)
- `adjustViewBounds` for setting bounds to match image dimensions
- some transformations such as alpha-setting

And more that you may find in [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html).

Answer (score 0):

Change  `android:background="@drawable/face"` to  `android:src="@drawable/face"`
Scale type will only work for`android:src`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `android:src` instead of `android:background` to set your drawable. Something like:

```
<ImageView  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/face"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

Also, Why not just crop the image using an image editor software like photoshop and use that image instead? Dynamically scaling and manipulating images should be avoided to prevent heavy use of system resources as far as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think, your problem is  inserted weights in LinearLayout and FrameLayout. Please use RelativeLayout without weight. System can not crop your picture  because system can not  measure ImageView and can not compare him with your picture. In sum system thinks "This is picture and ImageView equal".
I have done so :

```
 <RelativeLayout        
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:padding="5dp">

      <ImageView 
          android:id="@+id/image"
          android:layout_height="50dp"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:src="@drawable/photo"
          android:scaleType="centerCrop"
          android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
          />
      <TextView android:layout_height="150dp"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:text="@string/text"
          android:layout_below="@id/image"
          android:maxLength="350"
          android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```